# エクセルファイルで選択したセルのみコメントを表示させたい。

Tags: vba, excel

エクセルファイルで選択したコメントのみ表示させたくマクロ作成中ですが、全然できず・・。
”Set pComment = Selection.Cells”　これで、自分が選択したセルだけ対応してね～って指示したいんですが、ずっとエラーで、ネットで検索してもなぜかでてこず。範囲は指定しないとダメ的なサイトは見つけましたが・・・。どなたかお力を貸してください。特定のファイルではなく、いろんなファイルで使えるマクロを作成したく思っております。

Sub 選択したセルのみコメント表示する()

```
Dim pComment As Comment
```

For Each pComment In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
Set pComment = Selection.Cells
pComment.Comment.Visible = True
Next

End Sub

よろしくお願いします。

※すいません。下記でうまくいきました！！
Sub AllCommentVisibleTrue()
On Error Resume Next
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
c.Comment.Visible = True
Next c
End Sub

Comment: すいません。解決しました！Sub AllCommentVisibleTrue()
 On Error Resume Next
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection
        c.Comment.Visible = True
    Next c
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マクロモジュール作ってを別のブックにコピーしてみてはどうですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。色々検索したら解決しました！